# How can I remove junk characters from a file?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file that contains text like the following. How can I remove the "junk" characters like `^[[H` using Perl ?

```
^[[H^[[2J^[(B^[[mtop - 19:25:22 up 69 days, 23:25,  2 users,  load average: 2.55, 2.15, 1.83^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[[K
Tasks:^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m 114 ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mtotal,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m   1 ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mrunning,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m 113 ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49msleeping,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m   0 ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mstopped,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m   0 ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mzombie^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[[K
Cpu(s):^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m 18.1%^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mus,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m  0.5%^[(B^[[m^[[39;49msy,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m  0.0%^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mni,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m 81.2%^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mid,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m  0.0%^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mwa,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m  0.0%^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mhi,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m  0.2%^[(B^[[m^[[39;49msi,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m  0.0%^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mst^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[[K
em: ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m 16435100k ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mtotal,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m  3081324k ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mused,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m 13353776k ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mfree,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m   196396k ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mbuffers^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[[K
Swap:^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m  4194296k ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mtotal,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m        0k ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mused,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m  4194296k ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mfree,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m  1531300k ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mcached^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[[K
^[[6;1H
^[[7m  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                    ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[[K
^[(B^[[m22285 root      25   0 4931m 398m  11m S 47.6  2.5 545:13.49 java                                                                                                       ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m
^[(B^[[m19235 root      17   0 1406m 624m  10m S  2.0  3.9   6203:15 java                                                                                                       ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m
^[(B^[[m    1 root      15   0 10368  684  572 S  0.0  0.0   0:09.51 init                                                                                                       ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m
^[(B^[[m    2 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   2:02.87 migration/0                                                                                                ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m
^[(B^[[m    3 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.27 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m
^[(B^[[m    4 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   2:00.50 migration/1                                                                                                ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m
^[(B^[[m    5 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.26 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                                ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m
^[(B^[[m    6 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   2:04.21 migration/2                                                                                                ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m
^[(B^[[m    7 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.26 ksoftirqd/2                                                                                                ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m
^[(B^[[m    8 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   1:52.52 migration/3                                                                                                ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not an applicable question.

Comment: @MitchWheat Please give me a solution

Comment: @MitchWheat What does that even mean?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable enough question to me, but why is it tagged perl?

Comment: @AndrewSpencer Perhaps because the OP wants to process the file with Perl?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes you are correct .. I want to process the file with PERL.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot That to my mind is a sufficient constraint on the answer space to warrant more explanation than a tag. But never mind. A mere detail.

Comment: Nit: The name of the language is "Perl", not "PERL".

Comment: @AndrewSpencer: Yes i can understand. But i am stuck in a real time production issue. so was in a hurry for a solution. In-fact,  still !!!

Comment: @AndrewSpencer That's exactly what tags are for. If you think it's unclear, though, feel free to edit the question.

Comment: Useful comment now: similar question here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4527/program-that-passes-stdin-to-stdout-with-color-codes-stripped

Comment: @Venkatesh There is no reason to add the [tag:regex] tag. There are other ways besides regexes to solve your problem. People will still offer regex solutions if they're appropriate, whether the tag is there or not (unlike language-specific tags like [tag:perl]).

Comment: @Venkatesh SO is not a code-writing service. People expect you to have made some preliminary effort at solving the problem yourself, and to show the code you have written so far in your attempt.

Comment: Those who speak American English may wish to know that *nit* in British English means a fool, as well as a louse egg. So it would be more prudent to spell *nitpick* in full on international sites.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Term::ANSIColor`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ANSIColor) module,

```
perl -MTerm::ANSIColor=colorstrip -ne 'print colorstrip $_' file
```